# Linear interpolation for vertices to achieve faceted appearance in Metal

Tags: graphics, rendering, metal

I was trying to make an artistic look with Metal. The effect to achieve is to render a faceted teapot based on triangle primitives, instead of a smooth and mellow teapot. I am not sure how I can do this. I know I should tell Metal to calculate pixels inside a triangle as if the triangle is planar, instead of looking at nearby triangles and interpolate pixels. Should I do this in vertex function, or do some setting with rasterization process?

[image: teapot]

(Image: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/art-reference-utah-teapot-4c02605ea63541b6aa053df167befe36)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing that controls how the faces will look is attribute interpolation.

There are many different kinds of interpolation, and you can check them out in Metal Shading Language Specification (https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf, 5.4 Sampling and Interpolation Attributes
).

If you want a flat look, there are two ways to do it: you will either want to use `flat` interpolation or change the initial model.

You can set up interpolation in shader code. You will need to decorate your fragment shader inputs with attributes for interpolation.

If you have directional lighting or any other lighting, to achieve this flat look your normals will need to be flat across the faces, to do that you want to mark fragment shader inputs somewhat like this

```
struct FragmentInput
{
    float3 position;
    float4 color;
    float3 normal [[flat]];
};
```

Flat interpolation will use data from the first vertex in a triangle and use it for the whole triangle.

And result will also somewhat depend on the initial vertex data itself.

Other way is to just have vertices that belong to one face (in your case one face is square consisting of two triangles) have the same value for normal. This way your model will have more vertices (some of the vertices will share the same position, but they will belong to different faces). You should be able to do it in any 3D editor.

You can try and experiment with different kinds of interpolation for achieving different looks.

Thanks to @warrenm for the comment about provoking vertex.

Comment: Flat interpolation uses the same value across the entire primitive, but as you allude, you also need to consider which vertex's values are used. OpenGL and DirectX have different default conventions for choosing the so-called [provoking vertex](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Provoking_vertex), and AFAIK Metal doesn't declare a convention or make it configurable. To get "correct" face normals, one may need to duplicate the vertices in the teapot and set each vertex's normal to its face's normal, or else store the normals separately and fetch them explicitly by `vertex_id`.

Comment: @warrenm, you are right that you can achieve that look by changing the initial vertices, but I think `flat` will also work. By the way, provoking vertex is first vertex as described here (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html)

Comment: @warrenm, I've updated the answer to include the other way as you mentioned, thanks.

Comment: Nice, I had forgotten that was documented. My main concern was that if you use a model created with "smooth" normals (i.e., one where the normal of a vertex is the weighted average of the faces it belongs to, and coincident vertices are deduplicated via indexing), those normals won't be what you want for flat shading. Even with very careful authoring of which vertex occurs first in each triangle, by the pigeonhole principle, you can't produce a single suitable normal for each vertex without some duplication.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, since faces are actually triangles and not squares. But maybe he'll find flat interpolation useful.

Comment: So, in `flat` interpolation, each fragment's position in the world view as well as camera view will be different from that in regular setting. Does ``[[flat]]`` tell Metal to calculate the position using flat interpolation as well?

Comment: Meanwhile, I learned that some applications allow polygon primitives to represent faces. That is so lit.

Comment: @jackxujh The `[[flat]]` attribute is not allowed on the position variable. If you think about it, that wouldn't be especially useful, since every primitive would wind up with zero area. But you can control the interpolation of most other kinds of fragment-varying data.

Comment: I think you meant section 5.4